# How to anchor QGraphicsWidget/Item (make them static) on QGraphicsView

Tags: qt, qt4, pyqt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem

I want to make something like a hud. I have a `QGraphicsScene` with a huge `QPixmap`, that I added to a much smaller `QGraphicsView`. Now I need to add some control elements, like `QLabel`, `QPushButton` and `QGraphicsEllipseItem`. That's, I think, is not a problem. I found this helpful page [Graphics View Classes](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/graphicsview-api.html). But how do I anchor this control elements to the View or maybe better said how do I not anchor them? When I drag the `QPixmap`, then I don't want that the hud is moving with the `QPixmap` out of the `QGraphicsView`.
What do I need to do, to solve this problem. Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should just have to create your widgets and specify the `QGraphicsView` in the constructor like this:

```
QPushButton *button1 = new QPushButton(view);
```

Comment: This doesn't work for `QGraphicsEllipseItem`, or any other non-widget graphics item.