# Forcing QGraphicsItem To Stay Put

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem

I have a `QGraphicsScene` that is filled with `QGraphicsItems`, and the user is able to pan and zoom around to inspect all of the various `QGraphicsItems`. However, I would like to have a  `QGraphicsTextItem` label that always stays put at the top left of the screen. Ignoring the zooms is easy, as I can just `setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIgnoresTransformations)`, but I've yet to figure out how to force the position to stay at the top-left. What's the best way to make my label "float" in the same place?

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17373210/fixed-qgraphicsitem-position-without-changing-behaviour-of-other-qgraphicsitems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you just want to put a regular `QLabel` right on the view instead of trying to make a part of the scene stay in one place as discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683565/how-to-anchor-qgraphicswidget-item-make-them-static-on-qgraphicsview).

**Note:** As mentioned in another answer, this trick will often not work with hardware accelerated views. In these cases, you will need to make the text items a part of the scene.

Answer (score 7):

I think the only (realiable) way to do that is to recalculate position for your text item every frame. To do this, simply subclass QGraphicsView, override paintEvent and use QGraphicsView::mapToScene() to calculate new position. Something like:

```
void MyGraphicsView::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)
{
    QPointF scenePos = mapToScene(0,0); // map viewport's top-left corner to scene
    m_textItem->setPos(scenePos);
}
```

I have done this many many times and it has worked very well.

Of course you could just create normal QLabel like Arnold Spence mentions in his answer. However, this won't work in many situations (e.g. if you really want to place label on top of graphics view and you are using OpenGL-accelerated viewport).

Comment: I was think of doing this, but won't the setPos call trigger an update, which will trigger a paintEvent, which will call setPos, etc..?

Comment: No it won't. Give it a try and you will see :).

Comment: Question, this requires me to re-implement the whole paintEvent for a scene? I would still like everything else within the scene to behave as usual. Calling QGraphicsView::paintEvent() in the beginning of my custom paintEvent() and then adding my extra code results in a flickering behaviour, since the original paintEvent first sets a position which I then set it to my custom position.

Comment: This solution has bad performance and architectural implications. The index of the scene needs to be refreshed every time you move the item. You're also breaking the model-view paradigm: the view is constantly messing with the model. While it will work with multiple views due to serial nature of the processing in the GUI thread, it's only a happy coincidence.