# Graphics Viewport coordinates after scrolling

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview

Here is a class i use for the viewport to zoom in/out.
zoom.cpp

```
#include "zoom.h"
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QScrollBar>
#include <qmath.h>

Graphics_view_zoom::Graphics_view_zoom(QGraphicsView* view)
  : QObject(view), _view(view)
{
  _view->viewport()->installEventFilter(this);
  _view->setMouseTracking(true);
  _modifiers = Qt::ControlModifier;
  _zoom_factor_base = 1.001;
  initfactor=1;

}


QList<int> Graphics_view_zoom::gentle_zoom(double factor) {

  _view->scale(factor, factor);
  _view->centerOn(target_scene_pos);
  QPointF delta_viewport_pos = target_viewport_pos - QPointF(_view->viewport()->width() / 2.0,
                                                             _view->viewport()->height() / 2.0);
  QPointF viewport_center = _view->mapFromScene(target_scene_pos) - delta_viewport_pos;
  zpoint=_view->mapToScene(viewport_center.toPoint()); //zpoint is public QPointF
  _view->centerOn(_view->mapToScene(viewport_center.toPoint()));

  emit zoomed();
  zooms.append(viewport_center.x());
  zooms.append(viewport_center.y());
  zooms.append(_view->viewport()->x());
  zooms.append(_view->viewport()->y());
  return zooms;

}

void Graphics_view_zoom::set_modifiers(Qt::KeyboardModifiers modifiers) {
  _modifiers = modifiers;

}

void Graphics_view_zoom::set_zoom_factor_base(double value) {
  _zoom_factor_base = value;
}

bool Graphics_view_zoom::eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *event) {

  if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseMove || event->type()==QEvent::Scroll) {
    QMouseEvent* mouse_event = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);
    QPointF delta = target_viewport_pos - mouse_event->pos();
    if (qAbs(delta.x()) > 5 || qAbs(delta.y()) > 5) {
      target_viewport_pos = mouse_event->pos();
      target_scene_pos = _view->mapToScene(mouse_event->pos());

    }
  } else if (event->type() == QEvent::Wheel) {
    QWheelEvent* wheel_event = static_cast<QWheelEvent*>(event);
    if (QApplication::keyboardModifiers() == _modifiers) {
      if (wheel_event->orientation() == Qt::Vertical) {
        angle = wheel_event->angleDelta().y();
        steps=steps+angle;
        factor = qPow(_zoom_factor_base, angle);
        initfactor=qPow(_zoom_factor_base,0-steps);

        gentle_zoom(factor);
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  Q_UNUSED(object)
  return false;
}
```

zoom.h

```
#ifndef ZOOM_H
#define ZOOM_H


#include <QObject>
#include <QGraphicsView>

class Graphics_view_zoom : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  Graphics_view_zoom(QGraphicsView* view);
  QList<int> gentle_zoom(double factor);
  void set_modifiers(Qt::KeyboardModifiers modifiers);
  void set_zoom_factor_base(double value);
  double _zoom_factor_base;
  double angle;
  double factor;
  double initfactor;
  int steps=0;
  QList<int> zooms;

  QPointF target_scene_pos;
  QPointF zpoint;
  int slposx;

  QGraphicsView* _view;
  Qt::KeyboardModifiers _modifiers;

  QPointF target_viewport_pos;

  bool eventFilter(QObject* object, QEvent* event);

private:

signals:
  void zoomed();
};

#endif // ZOOM_H
```

I need to add a GraphicsItem (which is also sub-classed to either the center of the viewport or ideally at its top-left corner. What i managed to get from this class is the center of the view (see zpoint variable in gentle_zoom(). However, it only works if mouse wheel is used to zoom. If i then move the scrollbar of the Graphics view (which is in a Ui HLayout and auto-adjusts), the item is added to the previous position and doesn't follow the scrolling i did with mouse.
How can i get that ? I assume i have to add some event to the eventFilter(), but unsure of what is that. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it was much easier than i thought. After studying the zoom class, i realized that i was storing the initial zoom factor (initfactor variable), so all i had to do for my new GraphicsItem was ..

```
item->setX(ceil(ui->graphicsView->horizontalScrollBar()->value()*z->initfactor));
item->setY(ceil(ui->graphicsView->verticalScrollBar()->value()*z->initfactor));
```

... and the item was added at the top-left position of my zoomed view.

@Noah Whitehouse Thanks for the heads up, the `horizontalScrollBar()->value()` was actually the one that lead me to the solution

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps add the `_view-horizontalScrollBar()->value()` (or vertical) to the zpoint. So keep track of the last scrollbar position when you zoom, then when you add an item after scrolling you add (newScrollPosition - lastScrollPosition) to your center point.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to have a view-bound item that ignores transformations (i.e. zoom). One approach is to have an item with `QGraphicsItem::ItemIgnoresTransformations` flag set. It'd make sense when the untransformed "UI" items are shared among all views.

Another is to overlay a second, transparent graphics view on top of the primary one, and show the "static" (un-zoomable) UI there, from a dedicated scene. This makes sense when each view needs its own custom UI that's not shared between the views. You may refer to [this, albeit not fully fleshed out yet working, answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18412183/1329652).

As a colossal hack, you can use the first approach for the UI items for all views, but instead have dedicated untransformed item(s) for each view, and do nothing if `paint(..., widget)` is not the items desired view.